# Is there a way to avoid prompting user for permission to share location on every load in Safari (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, safari, geolocation

I have developed a Web application (HTML5/browser based) for a client which requires fairly continuous polling of location information.  Client generally uses an iPhone or iPad.  The complaint is that the device requests permission to "share location" just as continuously, and wanted to know if there was a way to allow device to "remember" their choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no - not with HTML.